# How would I implement friends relationship between users in Firebase Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I go about implementing a friends relationship between users, using Firebase in swift?

The following is my current DataService.swift file.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

let DB_BASE = Database.database().reference()

class DataService {
    // creates instance of the class inside itself
    static let instance = DataService()

    private var _REF_BASE = DB_BASE
    private var _REF_USERS = DB_BASE.child("users")

    var REF_BASE: DatabaseReference {
        return _REF_BASE
    }

    var REF_USERS: DatabaseReference {
        return _REF_USERS
    }

    func createDBUser(uid: String, userData: Dictionary<String,Any>) {
        REF_USERS.child(uid).updateChildValues(userData)
    }

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: We're going to be need a bit more to go on, What's you current users structure look like? What defines a 'friend'? How will you be using friends? What's the purpose of a friend?

Comment: Friends will use a qr code scanner to create a relationship with each other and the purpose is to allow friends to share details(which will be added to the users structure or a separate structure later). My current users structure is just the default one with just email and the uid that firebase creates. If you need any more information, just let me know, thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just add a friends child node within each users node and store their friends uid's there? So for example, uid_0 has two friends uid_1 and uid_2:  /users/uid_0/friends/uid_1: true and /users/uid_0/friends/uid_2: true. If you are not querying or performing any other functions, that's a pretty simple solution.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of doing, however, I am unsure how to do it. If you would be able to write an answer showing me how, I will select it as the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is a very complete answer but may get you going in the right direction

Assume we have three users in Firebase and there is data is stored in a /users node. Larry (uid_0) has two friends, Moe and Curly

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Larry"
    friends:
       uid_1: true
       uid_2: true
  uid_1
    name: "Moe"
  uid_2
    name: "Curly"
```

The code to write the friends node is something like this

```
let usersRef = fbRed.child("users")
let uid0Ref = usersRef.child("uid_0")
let friendsRef = uid0Ref.child("friends")
friendsRef.child("uid_1").setValue(true)
friendsRef.child("uid_2").setValue(true)
```

That's pretty verbose and could be condensed but leaving that way for readability.

Note that *if* you are going to do queries or other functions in the future, this is probably not the best solution.

Comment: At the end you said that this is not the best solution for queries, does that mean that this would not be suitable for displaying users friends in a table view for example?

Comment: Actually, I said that if you are doing queries it *may* not be the best solution. That comes back to fanning out / denormalization, which is common in NoSQL databases. The bottom line is that in Firebase, your structure is dependent on what you want to get out of it. To answer you specific question, there's no problem populating a tableView using that structure.

Answer (score 3):

Each user should have a list of ***references*** to other users via their uid. Do not store the entire friend user data object under each user. This will greatly inflate your database.

```
users ->
    "uid1" ->
        friendUids ->
            0 ->
                "uid2"
            1 ->
                "uid3"
    "uid2" ->
        friendUids ->
            0 ->
                "uid1"
    "uid3" ->
        friendUids ->
            0 ->
                "uid1"
```

Assuming you have a static decode function on your user to handle the JSON from Firebase, all you need to do to retrieve the user data is:

```
extension DataService {

    func requestUserWithUid(_ uid: String, completion: @escaping (User?) -> Void) {
        REF_USERS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            completion(User.decode(snapshot.value))
        }
    }

    func requestFriendsForCurrentUser(completion: @escaping ([User?]?) -> Void) {
        var friends = [User?]()

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(.none)
            return
        }

        requestUserWithUid(uid) { user in
            guard let user = user else {
                completion(.none)
                return
            }

            for friendUid in user.friendUids {
                requestUserWithUid(friendUid) { friend in
                    friends.append(friend)
                }
            }

            completion(friends)
        }
    }
}
```

This is just limited example of many of how you could implement it. Let's assume your user data object has a name and we want to display a list of friends' names.

```
class FriendView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource {

    fileprivate var friends = [User?]()

    fileprivate let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: UIView
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.frame = frame
        tableView.dataSource = self

        loadFriends()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder :) has not been implemented")
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Private
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    fileprivate func loadFriends() {
        DataService.instance.requestFriendsForCurrentUser() { friends in
            if let friends = friends {
                self.friends = friends
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return friends.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = friends[indexPath.row]?.name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I get an error saying `Type 'User' has no member 'decode'` and `Value of type 'User' has no member 'friendUids'` is their something I am missing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `decode` is a custom function I wrote for my data objects. If you use the protocol `Codable` for your User struct, it should exist, although the syntax might look a little different than what's here. Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types